# Bootstrap buttons and link buttons are different with same class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, class, button, sass

I have two buttons (classic button and link button) in Bootstrap 4 beta but they are displayed in two different ways.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Verify</button>

<a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Verify</a>
```

The same happens with all my buttons (even if they don't have .btn-block class). I use scss and comment all my import to be sure I don't have a conflict in my code and the issue is the same.

[image: First is button, second link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some error is in the second line of code, according to Bootstrap documentation I should write "role='button'" and not "type='button'":

```
<a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Verify</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**The CSS type selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) matches elements by node name. In other words, it selects all elements of the given type within a document.

for example you may have in you css :

```
 a {
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

or

```
button {
 border-radius:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other stylesheets that could be applying other styles to your `<a>` tags? The elements look identical using the HTML you posted (see [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tm209wy/)):

[image]